# Vector spaces - Proving that intersection is distributive over summation of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**The problem**

Define the *sum* of two vector spaces (often two subspaces of a common vector space) $A$ and $B$ as $A+B=\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B \}.$ Let $U,V,W$ be arbitrary vector spaces. I want to show that

> $$U \cap (V+W)=(U \cap V)+(U \cap W)$$

**My approach**

By starting with $x \in (U \cap V)+(U \cap W)$ and applying the properties of vector spaces (closure under *vector addition*) to end up with $x \in U \cap (V+W)$, I've shown that $(U \cap V)+(U \cap W) \subset U \cap (V+W)$.

My problem is with the reverse, i.e. showing that $U \cap (V+W) \subset (U \cap V)+(U \cap W)$. Following the usual procedure, I started with:

$x \in U \cap (V+W)$, which implies that $x \in U \land x \in V+W$.

Now, $x \in V+W \implies x=y+z$ for some $y \in V$ and some $z \in W$.

Again, $x=y+z \in U$. If we could show that $y$ and $z$ both comes from $U$, then we will be done. But unfortunately $y+z \in U$ doesn't necessarily imply that $y \in U$ and $z \in U.$ Am I missing some very basic properties of *vector spaces* that would make this trivial? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** Just a dumb question. Does the result break down if we replace *vector spaces* by *arbitrary sets* in the above problem?

Comment: You say "*often* two subspaces of a common vector space", but what does "$a+b$" mean when $a$ and $b$ are not in the same vector space?

Comment: For this identity to work Either of V or W has to be a subspace of U.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The statement is wrong. If $U$, $V$ and $W$ are all lines in the same plane ($U\neq V$, $V\neq W$ and $W\neq U$) then $U\cap (V+W) = U$ but $(U\cap V)+(U\cap W)$ = $\{0\}+\{0\} =\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is from page 2 of one of [Hochster's notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/615W07/L01.08.pdf):

Consider a $K$-vector space with basis $\mathcal B$, and let $\mathcal S$ be the set of $K$-vector subspaces that are spanned by a subset of $\mathcal B$. Then there is an order-preserving bijection between $\mathcal S$ and the set of subsets of $\mathcal B$. This bijection preserves intersection, even infinite intersection, and takes sums, even infinite sums, to unions. Thus, for such a family of vector spaces, intersection distributes over sum (even when the sum is infinite) and union distributes over intersection (even if the intersection is infinite).

(**NOTE**: There is an error in the final remark of the last sentence. It should say "sum distributes over intersection".)